# When calling selector that has NSAutoreleasePool, why are somethings in Pool left allocated after releasing it?

Tags: objective-c, nsautoreleasepool

I am calling a selector which I want to use to fire off a background process with the following

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startSync) withObject:nil];
```

For an example, lets say startSync looks something like this

```
-(void)startSync {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    // expensive background process
    Sync *sync = [Sync new];
    [sync performSync];
    [sync release];
    [pool release];
}
```

The really intensive processing is happening in "performSync" of the sync object.  It's retrieving some XML, parsing it into an array, and inserting it into a MySQL database.  The process itself seems to be working fine and the Analyzer isn't showing any leaks, but using the profiler and doing a baseline Heap Mark at the beginning before it runs and then again after it runs is showing about a 5mb gain.  To the best of our knowledge (no pun intended) we are properly allocating and releasing objects in the performSync process.

The question is I am running this process in the background, if I am creating an AutoreleasePool for it, and releasing it at the end of the background process, shouldn't it dealloc everything related to the background process when it is over?  I don't have a good understanding of why all of the allocated objects aren't getting destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

The release will only happen at the end of the event loop

Comment: When you say at the end of the event loop are you referring to when sync performSync is complete?  I've put in NSLog statements to show me that it has completed.  I've done a baseline heap mark and one after the process and it's showing that there are roughly 5mb of objects left occupying memory that were used when sync performSync executed.

Answer (score 0):

We were missing a close database statement each time we were doing a record insert, which was creating more connections and causing our problem.  After doing so, our baseline heap mark was at 1.22mb and our ending heap mark was 1.22mb, exactly as I was expecting.